# Как использовать введённое в консоли число в качестве индекса массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import random
mas = []
for x in range(10):
    a = random.randrange(0, 10)
   #mas.append(a)
print('Полученный массив',mas)
print("подсказка:Индексы элемента начинаються с 0.")
num1 = input('Введите индекс 1 элемента: ')
num2 = input('Введите индекс 2 элемента: ')
summ = mas[num1]+mas[num2]
print(summ)
```

Как добавить введенный индекс из input в скобки массива `summ = mas[num1]+mas[num2]`

Comment: например, int(input(...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` возвращает строку, а чтобы взять элемент списка нужно использовать число. Чтобы строке превратить в число используйте `int`:

```
num1 = int(input('Введите индекс 1 элемента: '))
num2 = int(input('Введите индекс 2 элемента: '))
```